# Infinite running client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

what I want to do is write a program that listens wcf web service frequently , say once every half-hour, and updates db according to ws result.What is the proper way of writing that kind of program.Should I create an exe and make it a windows scheduled task or write a program that has an infinite loop , maybe a thread approach.What is your opinion ?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: windows scheduled task would be better as incase your exe got terminated,it will resume it.

Comment: You need to create a windows service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to create a [Windows Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx):

> Microsoft Windows services, formerly known as NT services, enable you
>   to create long-running executable applications that run in their own
>   Windows sessions. These services can be automatically started when the
>   computer boots, can be paused and restarted, and do not show any user
>   interface. These features make services *ideal for use on a server or
>   whenever you need long-running functionality that does not interfere
>   with other users who are working on the same computer*.

In order to implement a recurring event, you need to use the [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

On a second thought, supported by these references:

- [windows service vs scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16677855/674700)
- [Windows Service or Scheduled Task, which one do we prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767490/674700)
- [//TODONT: Use a Windows Service just to run a scheduled process](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx)

a scheduled task seems also a nice solution which fits your scenario.

In terms of available .NET libraries, there is no difference between the 2 alternatives.

Comment: Thank you reply , but is there any restrictions of .net libraries if I use Windows Service Application.Can I get the advantage of .net libraries.I will use c# by the way.

Comment: Yes you can use the .NET libraries and write it in C#